# glMapBuffer returns random values

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

I am trying to get the vertices in a VBO to generate a fitting bounding box but the values returned from glMapBuffer are random.

Here is my code:

```
//Data (Quad):
FloatBuffer vertexData = FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    });
```

Storing vertices:

```
//Generating IDs
int vaoID = glGenVertexArrays();
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
int vboID = glGenBuffers();

//Storing vertex data in attribute list
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

//Unbinding
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Loading Vertices:

```
//Binding VAO and VBO
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
ByteBuffer vertexBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

//Printing values
//vertices.flip(); //Do I have to flip it? No, right?
System.out.println("Capacity: " + vertices.capacity() + ", Limit: " + vertices.limit()); 
//Capacity: 48, Limit: 48, Position: 0
while(vertices.remaining() != 0) {
    System.out.print("x: " + vertices.get());
    System.out.print(", y: " + vertices.get());
    System.out.println(", z: " + vertices.get());
}

//Unbinding
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The output are random values (mostly just zeros but sometimes random). GlGetError() returns 0 (no errors).

Is this a reasonable way to generate bounding boxes or just dumb? Why are the values random?

Comment: I really think you need to call glEnableVertexAttribArray() after glVertexAttribPointer()

Comment: I've tried calling glEnableVertexAttribArray(0) at the suggested locations and many others but it didn't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is in something you're not showing: `glMapBuffer` returns a `ByteBuffer`, so aren't you getting the 4 bytes that make up each float one at a time? So either try casting it to `FloatBuffer` with `vertices.asFloatBuffer`, or use `getFloat()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: I know that but that's not my problem. If I do that the values will still be random every time that I run my program.